# 2D Array Random Path

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, random

I am developing a text based adventure game and I am implementing a small map feature. I am trying to make an algorithm that randomizes a map with results similar the the one below. However, I haven't had much luck getting map shapes to look like this. Does anybody have any solutions?

EDIT: Apologies for poor explanation, I am new to this site. The path shows a top down view of a path in which the player will walk forward, left, right, and back. As far as the generation, I believe I found a solution! The steps I took were to pick two random points in opposing quadrants and then connect, and repeat.

■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
■▣■■■▣■■■■■■▣▣▣▣■■■■
■■▣▣▣▣▣■■■■■■■▣■■■■■
■■■■■■▣▣▣▣▣■■■▣■■■■■
■■■■■■■■■▣■■■■▣■■■■■
■■■■▣▣▣▣▣▣▣▣▣▣▣▣■■■■
■■■■▣■■■▣■■■▣■■■■■■■

(▣ shows a path tile)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have an example, but it's not clear to me what it's supposed to show. Is it supposed to be platforms which with a player could walk on with gravity? Or just any group of tiles which have adjacent (including diagonal) tiles? A detailed description of your expectations in your question would be helpful.

Comment: @Knox    Sorry! I apologize for the lack of detail, but I've since found a solution to my problem. Thanks for the helpful criticism however :)

Comment: No need to apologize, glad you got it sorted. If you believe others would find it helpful and you have enough reputation (?), you can answer your own question if you'd like.